# How to open the SQL profiler?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 installed on my PC. It was installed along with Microsoft Visual studio 2010.

With this configuration, is there any way to open SQL Profiler?

For information, SQL Server Configuration manager and SQL Server Installation Centre are also installed.

Comment: The version that comes with Visual Studio is the **Express** edition which does **not** include SQL profiler.

Answer (score 2):

The program group that gets installed with Visual Studio is only those two tools for the SQL Express edition that gets installed.  You typically need to install Developer, Standard, or Enterprise edition client tools to get the Profiler utility included.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free one available at: https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/